# Building index based on column/category

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, indexing

My dataset with 2 columns (in reality 22) looks like this:

```
filename1 -"123"
filename1 -"xyz"
filename1 -"abc"
filename2 -"123"
filename2 -"Pieter"
etc.
```

I want to work my way through it in blocks based on filename. For this I need to return the vertical range of one or more columns based on filename (sorted in ascending order).

Right now I'm building an index using a dictionary. With a simple loop that counts each unique value so filename 1, 3 - filename 2, 2 etc and then a second loop to read out the number of rows per filename. With this I can of course calculate my way through it. But is there a different, maybe smarter technique?

```
Set dictFilenames = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

For Each row In Range("A:A")
    file = row.Value
    If Len(file) > 0 Then dictFilenames(file) = dictFilenames(file) + 1
Next row

For i = 0 To dictFilenames.Count - 1
    Debug.Print dictFilenames.Keys()(i), dictFilenames.Items()(i)
Next
```

Comment: That looks fine to me,unless you want to store the actual range for each filename, instead of just the count.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary can hold a dictionary as an Item

```
If Not dictfilenames.exists(file) then

    dictfilenames.add, file, New Scripting.Dictionary  ' or CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary)

End If

with dictfilenames.Item(file)

    .Add key:=.count, Item:=<value from next column>

End With
```

In this way you get a dictionary where the keys are the file names and the item is another scripting.dictionary with sequential keys starting at 0.  Of course you don't need to use the count to auto index, you could use the row number of the value in the next column.

e.g.

```
    .add key:=<row_number>, Item:=<value from next column>
```

You can now read back the values in the  nested dictionary using

```
Dim myItem as variant
For each myItem in dictfilenames.item(file) ' myItem is the key in the nested dictionary
    myValue = dictfilenames.item(file).item(myItem)
Next
```

or get an array of

```
Dim myArray as variant
myArray = dictfilenames.item(file).Items
```